# Teste logico dentro do array em Python

Tags: array, python-3.x, r, if

No R posso ter esta estrutura

```
var1 <-TRUE
var2 <-FALSE
paste0("ANO_544, SEMANA",
      if(var1 == TRUE){", COD_NEGOCIO"},
      if(var2 == TRUE){", CATEGORIA"},
      ", MODULADO")
```

E tenho como resposta:

```
"ANO_544, SEMANA, COD_NEGOCIO, MODULADO"
```

Isto me é útil para fazer requisições em SQL, como:

```
library(DBI)
var1 <-TRUE
var2 <-FALSE
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)

var1 <-FALSE
var2 <-TRUE
dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT
                  disp,",
                       if(var1 == TRUE){"gear,"},
                       if(var2 == TRUE){"carb,"},
                       "avg(qsec)
                FROM mtcars
                  group by
                  disp",
                       if(var1 == TRUE){",gear"},
                       if(var2 == TRUE){",carb"}))
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Assim posso mudar a query trocando os valores de `var1` e  `var1`.

A pergunta: Existe uma estrutura desta em Python?
Posso fazer isso dentro do `pd.read_sql(" ".join([...]), cursor)` ?

Comment: Explique melhor seu problema, não entendi o que você quer fazer e que tipo de operação lógica que executar sobre o array. Onde esta teu código em Python? Coloque ele para facilitar.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro o que você deseja fazer. Você deseja que o retorno seja um array? E baseado em condicionais ele contenha ou não certos elementos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível, porque, caso a condição não for satisfeita, qual seria o valor retornado? Precisa haver um retorno. Mas, se houver um segundo valor caso a condição não for satisfeita, pode ser de diversas formas:

```
print(', '.join([
    'A',
    'B' if True else 'b',
    ('C', 'c')[False],
    'd' == 'D' or 'D',
    'e' != 'E' and 'E',
    False and 'f' or 'F'
]))
```

**Acho** (não tenho certeza) que essas são todas as possíveis formas de um "ternário"

Enão o jeito é ir adicionando à lista armazenada em uma variável:

```
lista = ['A']
if True: lista.append('B')
```

Ou então usar um valor específico para caso a condição não seja satisfeita e, depois, filtrar a lista, removendo as ocorrências desse valor:

```
l = ['A', 'B' if False else None]
l.remove(None)
```

Dependendo do caso, como uma concatenação de strings, basta usar um valor que não alterará o resultado final (por exemplo, uma string vazia `''`):

```
l = ['A', 'B' if False else '', 'C']
print(''.join(l)) //AC
```

Comment: Então posso retorna ```' '``` (vazio)?

Comment: Pode, mas não é como se não houvesse um valor. No teu caso pode funcionar, mas não será em todos

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia criar a lista com todos os campos e filtrar o resultado depois.

O módulo `itertools` tem a função [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) que "remove" os elementos de um iterável baseado no valor booleano de outro iterável.

Exemplo:

```
from itertools import compress

var1, var2 = True, False
lista = ["ANO_544", "SEMANA", "COD_NEGOCIO", "CATEGORIA", "MODULADO"]
filtros = [True, True, var1, var2, True]

resultado = ", ".join(compress(lista, filtros))

print(resultado)
```

<sup>Veja rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-424888-6333)</sup>

O que for `True` será incluído no resultado e o que for `False` não.